# Neither 'REQ_PERMS' nor 'SCOPE' is working - FB Authentication

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

For whatever reason, I cannot seem to request additional permissions on top of the basic information. I'm currently using a Code Igniter / Facebook framework found here:
https://bitbucket.org/deth4uall/facebook-ignited/

What am I doing incorrectly? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<pre>public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
    $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
    $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();
    return $this->getUrl(
        'www',
        'dialog/oauth',
        array_merge(array(
            'display' => 'popup',
            'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
            'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
            'state' => $this->state,
            'scope' =>"email,user_birthday, user_likes, user_interests, offline_access, publish_stream, read_friendlists"),
        $params));
}

</pre>
```

Comment: Are you modifying the `base_facebook.php` file?!! you know that you shouldn't be missing with the library! can you post your controller?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to edit a config.php file, not this. Scope was defined there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to edit anything in base_facebook.php.

Simply add this to your authentication file or wherever you want the login link:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "email,user_birthday, user_likes, user_interests, offline_access, publish_stream, read_friendlists"));
```